# Wordpress Page Hierarchy

Tags: template-hierarchy

I have the following page on a site in development:

http://telamon.com.s137737.gridserver.com/media/press/

I want to do some stuff outside the loop, so I created page-press.php based on my understanding of the WP page hierarchy (http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy). It isn't working. I've reset permalinks as well. This isn't the first time I've had problems here and I just ended up creating a template, but this should work shouldn't it?

Thanks

Brett

Comment: You need to explain your problem more clearly. What are you trying to do exactly? Show us your code for page-press.php. Also, are the *recent stories* shown on the link above within your loop or is that external to your loop?

Comment: Sorry, this is all fixed.  I still had a template assigned to the page in question (press), so it was taking priority.  The page you're now seeing is correct in that it is pulling in content from a custom post type (Recent Stories) after the standard page content from the loop.  Thanks for the follow-up

Comment: No problem, in that case can you please answer your own question and mark it as such (answered), in accordance with keeping this sites Q&A threads well maintained.

Answer (score 1):

This is all fixed. I still had a template assigned to the page in question (press), so it was taking priority. The page you're now seeing is correct in that it is pulling in content from a custom post type (Recent Stories) after the standard page content from the loop.

Thanks for the help.

Brett

Comment: Glad that you resolved your own question. Please make sure to click the checkmark next to your answer to indicate that this question has been solved.